# Read file of any extension in android programmatically

Tags: android

Just want to confirm that is it possible that when i click on file of any extension will open up with its compatible software in android phone or display me the list of software’s present in mobile which can open the file and if it didn't found any software it will indicate user to first download the software to open that particular file (All this thing need to be done pro grammatically).

Thanks.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to open the file you can use the following method, If there is no application that can handle given file, it simply shows a `Toast` saying no application found.

```
private void viewFile(String filePath, String title, int fileType) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + filePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String dataAndType = getIntentDataAndType(filePath);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, dataAndType);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Application found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED** : 
For finding the mime type of the file.

```
private String getIntentDataAndType(String filePath) {
        String exten = "";
        int i = filePath.lastIndexOf('.');
        // If the index position is greater than zero then get the substring.
        if (i > 0) {
            exten = filePath.substring(i + 1);
        }
        String mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(exten);
        mimeType = (mimeType == null) ? "*/*" : mimeType;
        return mimeType;
    }
```

Comment: Hey Kartheek, thanks for your reply , is  getIntentDataAndType is any method which you defined because when i am using your code its saying that i need to create that method separately.

Comment: I had removed the parameter the fileType, Now there is no such variable.

Comment: yup just have a look on your code seems that file type was not getting use anywhere in code ..sorry for that stupid question :D

Comment: Kartheek its opening all the applications available in device but what i need is that i just want to show only those applications which are related to that extension...is it possible ?

Comment: if the given file doesn't have any extension or there is no mime type associated to the given file then it shows all then applications.

Comment: yes i see that last line of your getIntentDataAndType method , Thanks anyway